# Do something when a char variable has a string "cd" in C (Newbie question)

Tags: c

I am very new to C and I'm writing something that will eventually be a shell or at least something like that. I have a char variable `command` and I have an if-statement that executes (or at least should) function `cd()`when char `command` has "cd" as a string. But it doesn't work for some reason and always executes `cd`.

Sorry if the explenation is trash but english is not my native language and I don't speak it well. Anyways, here is the code (please ignore that chdir doesnt do anything for now):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
int loop=1;
char command[512];

while (loop == 1) {

    FILE *command_file;
    command_file = fopen("/tmp/EXECUTE", "w");

    printf("SHELL > ");
    fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);
    fprintf(command_file, "%s", command);

    if (strcpy(command, "cd")) {
        cd();
    }
    else {
        printf("%s", command);
    }
    
    fclose(command_file);
    execution();
    }
}

void execution() {
char r;
    
    FILE *exec_file;
    exec_file = fopen("/tmp/EXECUTE", "r");
    
    system("sh /tmp/EXECUTE");
    
}

void cd() {
char path;

    printf("Enter a path: ");
    path = getc(stdin);
    chdir();

}
```

Sorry if the code is a bit cringy but I really need help! If you want just the if statement:

```
if (strcpy(command, "cd")) {
        cd();
    }
    else {
        printf("%s", command);
    }
```

Comment: There isn't really a question in there anywhere. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) reads and *includes* the newline in the string. So if the input is `cd` followed by a newline then `fgets` will put `"cd\n"` in the buffer.

   A Simple way to remove the newline is with the [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) function:

   ```
   command[strcspn(command, "\n")] = 0;
   ```
2. The second problem is that [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) returns ***zero*** (i.e. false) when the two strings matches. So your comparison should be:

   ```
   if (strcmp(command, "cd") == 0)
   ```

Oh, and as mentioned in a comment, you should use **`strcmp`** to compare strings, not `strcpy` which is string *copy*.

Comment: Perhaps also that he uses `strcpy` instead of `strcmp`